# Toilet flange issue. Any hope?

Tags: toilet, caulking, flange

The last plumber suggested glue-ing (caulking) the toilet to the floor without any bolts. Is that the best solution for this ? Attaching the photo. The old flange does not gap to fit in the screws / bolts. 
My experience level is 1/10 :)

Thank you for reading ! [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would get a repair flange (screws to the old one) then fire your plumber because he should know how to install this 10$ repair kit. Added there are compression flanges closer to 40$ that will also work but I would choose the <10$ option.

Comment: Thanks Ed :) This is helpful. I am now thinking maybe I can try save the $150+ and do it myself. 

 Do I have to remove the old flange ? 
 Is there enough space (from photo) to slide in the repair flange ? 
 Will a repair flange or a compression flange not increase the height and go higher than the tiles ?

Comment: The repair flange is a thin steel ring and can be used in most cases with just a few screws to hold it in place, the compression flange fits down inside the pipe and I usually cut the old one out and after installing the new one back fill with hydraulic cement but have General Contractor friends that say this is a waste of time but some still do it.